# tensorflow: undefined symbol: cudnnSetRNNDescriptor_v6

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

when I finished installing tensorflow (GPU_support,linux 14.04,python3.4) with virtualenv environment,under the instructions of the official website, i validated the installation with the command :python; import tensorflow; but there is an error:

- `import tensorflow as tf
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fangfang/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/fangfang/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/fangfang/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
  _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/fangfang/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  ***ImportError: /home/fangfang/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined symbol: cudnnSetRNNDescriptor_v6`***

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error, and so hopefully this solution will work for you...

What version of CuDNN are you using? I found that versions of `tensorflow-gpu` > 1.2 would fail to load while I had CuDNN v5.1.10 installed.

At the time I'm writing this, Tensorflow docs say you must have CuDNN v6. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#nvidia_requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support

So I just removed the old CuDNN binaries and headers:

`$ sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h`

`$ sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so`

`$ sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.5.1.10`

and any other remnants of v5.1.10. Then just download and copy the new v6 headers and binaries into those same locations.

This is a useful command to check your CuDNN version:

`$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`

Comment: i installed tensorflow for python2.7 by anaconda before and it works well. i checked my cuda version is 8. this time i installed tensorflow for python3, i think my cudnn version has no problem. i dont know why

Comment: And what version of CuDNN (not CUDA) do you have? There is a command provided above for printing it to the console.

Comment: yes,you are right. it is the cudnn's problem. and i found a very useful tool to change the cudnn's version. [link](https://github.com/dnzzcn/cuDNNv)

Comment: Glad it worked - an upvote would be much appreciated. The link you provided appears to be a shell script that automates the commands I specified above.